# Classifying pincode type using SVM in r

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, analytics, svm

This is my dataset ----> `df_train`

```
Address                                                  Pincode_type
flat no 3,cruz villa, sa - 200021                          5521 
plot 21,high street,  nz - 500034                          5524
room no12,pink seepz,  bl -300001                          1132
qbiz,almount park,    ls - 500034                          5524
papton_green,b-3,street1, sp-200021                        5521
rose villa,plot no3,    ai- 200021                         5521

class(df_train$Address) = factor

class(df_train$Pincode_type) = factor
```

I'm using SVM to classify  pincode_type based on Address using df_train dataset

This is my `df_test` data

```
 Address
blueton,shinville, ca-500034
treboss,plot-2, hs -200021
jacq apt,room no3, sp -300001   


class(df_test$Address) = "factor"
```

This is what I have tried

```
attach(df_train)
svm_mod=svm(as.factor(Address)~Pincode_type,data=df_train,type='C',kernal='linear')  #executes properly
summary(svm_mod)
SVM_Type:C-classification
SVM Kernal:radial
cost:1
gamma :0.0002187705
Number of support vectors:4636
Number of Classes :91
pred=predict(svm_mod,df_test$Address)
Error in 1:nrow(newdata) : argument of length 0
```

Also I have tried

```
pred=predict(svm_mod,as.character(df_test$Address))

Error in colnames <- '(' *tmp* value =c(Address..link.blueton
length of dimnames [2] not equal to array extent
```

Any help would be much appreciated..Thanks

Comment: Can you please share some example data (using `dput`)?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got through this just by changing it to data.frame()

```
pred=predict(svm_mod,newdata=data.frame(x=df_test$Address))
```